# Why am I not being able to import dateutil module in Python 3?

Tags: python3

I'm trying to use the Python 3 version of matplotlib module. I am getting errors about [dateutil](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3-dateutil&searchon=names) not being present even though I have installed this package. Shouldn't

```
import dateutil
```

work after installing the above package? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in case it matters.

Comment: Using `sudo apt-get install python3-dateutil`

Comment: No, not using a virtualenv

Comment: I uninstalled dateutil and reinstalled it and it is working now. Odd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First make sure that you are not trying to import the module after activating the [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/%E2%80%8E). If you have your virtualenv activated and didn't supply the argument `--system-site-packages` while creating it, the module won't be available to you to import in virtualenv.

If you are not using a virtualenv and still unable to import the module, then make sure that you are using the Python 3 interpreter and not the Python 2 interpreter. Since you installed the package for python3, it won't be available to import in python2 interpreter. Next try to purge and reinstall the module using:

```
sudo apt-get purge python3-dateutil
sudo apt-get install python3-dateutil
```

Purging the package and reinstalling it should fix any issues which was restricting to import the module.